# CSS3+JQuery - SlideDown Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently developping my company's website and in the gallery section, the managers wants a design like this:

[image: Screen]

Unfortunately, I don't know how I can do that... I tried searching Google but I didn't found anything.

It would be something like this and when you click on another `.item`, it close the current opened item and open the new one... the arrow should be below the item, centered with it. Also, when you click on the `.item.open` `<a>` link, it close the "pop-below" (similar to a popover but below instead of over...) if it is opened.

I know that my JQuery code will be something like:

```
$('.item a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).parent().removeClass('open'); // which would slide the details up
    } else {
         var $id = $(this).data('item-id');
         getItemDetail($id);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's a exemple HTML I'll be using:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="projects">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#item" data-item-id="exempleid" class="item-link">
                <img src="" alt="item">
            </a>
            <!-- HERE GOES THE DETAIL-PANE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone has an idea on how I could do that, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Have you any HTML to show?

Comment: Well, not now because the details pane (the blue section) will be created by an AJAX request when the item is clicked, then stored in the LocalStorage (or cookies if LS not available). So I can only show the gallery HTML...

Comment: Go to google images, search for any image, when you get the thumbnails for them, click on any one of them and it opens the way you have mentioned in your screenshot, I hope that gets to what you want. - @FrederickMarcoux

Comment: @NathanLee I tried to get the code already from Google but there source code isn't very readable and I don't want it exactly this way... But yes, it was a nice idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 hours of searching the huge Google database, I finally found the solution!

Here the link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

It is exactly what I wanted! Thanks for all the tips @Nathan Lee!

Answer (score 1):

I threw something together on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TfCZ/4/

It's not as pretty as what's demo'd in the article link from OP's answer, but it might serve as a starting point for an alternative way, if someone decides to hack their own.

JS:

```
(function($) {

    // Display a 'popover' below a element
    var displayMenu = function(el) {

        // Display location = (el's position + its height + 1px border)
        var bottomOfEl = $(el).offset().top + $(el).height() + 1 + 'px';

        // Add bottom margin to parent <ul> equivalent to popover height
        $(el).parent().addClass('active');

        // Display popover
        $('#popover')
            .hide()
            .css({
                'height': '0',
                'top': bottomOfEl
            })
            .show()
            .animate({'height': '80px'}, 'fast');
    };


    $(document.body).on('click', '.item', function(e) {
        // Close all others .item elements
        $('.item').not(this).removeClass('open');

        // Remove bottom margin from all other .item-lists
        $('.item-list').not( $(this).parent() ).removeClass('active');        

        // Open this
        $(this).addClass('open');

        // Display popover relative to this element
        displayMenu(this);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="popover" class="popover"></div>

<ul class="item-list">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="item-list">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.popover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: blue;

}

.item-list {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.item-list.active {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.item:before {
    content: '.item';    
}

.item.open:before {
    content: '.open';    
}

.item.open:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Man, you saved my life! You're solution is much easier! Thank you!